# ActiveRecord adding "DESC" randomly to ORDER BY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

When I call the following:

```
organization = Organization.first
organization.members.order("SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(members.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1)").last
```

Gives me the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'DESC, ' ' DESC, 3) DESC, ' ' DESC, -1) DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1: 
SELECT  `members`.* FROM `members`  WHERE `members`.`organization_id` = 2
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(members.name DESC, ' ' DESC, 3) DESC, ' ' DESC, -1) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Issue is in this statement:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(members.name DESC, ' ' DESC, 3) DESC, ' ' DESC, -1) DESC LIMIT 1
```

It adds "DESC" randomly to the `ORDER BY` statement. Is this an AR issue or am I doing something wrong?

**Note**: This only happens when I call `last`. I'm using ActiveRecord `4.1.1`.

Comment: It doesn't add DESC randomly.  It does it every time you add .last, correct?

Comment: I would call it "randomly" because it doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: I would call that "unexpectedly".

Comment: It doesn't behave the way it should. It should instead use the following SQL: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(members.name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) DESC` when I call `.last`. Unless that's the way AR was designed (which is a bad design).

Answer (score 0):

Something deep within the bowels of ActiveRecord or AREL is making assumptions about what commas mean in an SQL ORDER BY clause. The assumption is that the ORDER BY is a string that looks like `expr1, expr2, ...` with no commas inside the individual expressions.

When you add the `.last`, AR will eventually get around to calling [`reverse_order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reverse_order) on the query. `reverse_order` makes dumb assumptions about the format of the ORDER BY clause, it (or something it calls) assumes that an SQL ORDER BY looks like `expr1, expr2, ...` with no commas inside the individual expressions. When `reverse_order` attempts to reverse the order, it blindly splits the ORDER BY string on commas and pastes the pieces back together with `DESC`s in various places. This of course doesn't work if your ORDER BY uses "advanced" things like function calls.

You could add that function call to your SELECT and include an alias for it and then `.order('your_column_alias')` to hide the commas from AR.

You could also pretend that `last` doesn't exist and use `first` instead:

```
organization.members.order("SUBSTRING_INDEX(...) DESC").first
```

This of course assumes that you know the structure of the ORDER BY.